# Google Maps for iOS SDK - How to display a location via a name?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Using the web version of Google Maps, I can enter a general place, like a neighborhood, and it will show that neighborhood, with its borders directly highlighted. Like this:

[image: Google Maps - Neighborhood Highlight]

I want to be able to do this using the iOS SDK. However, I cannot determine through the documentation how to load a location by means other than a Lat/Long. Does this require the use of the Places API to work? If so, how?

Once I am able to display this, I want to display the user's current location on the screen, but keep the frame locked to the neighborhood. Basically, it will indicate to the user when they have wandered outside the specified area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps Api does NOT return neighborhood boundaries. You will have to build your own API for that.

If you're interested in NYC neighborhoods - I would contact the owner of [locality.nyc](http://locality.nyc) - he can provide you with an API for that.

Comment: Yeah, I sadly discovered this on my own a short while ago. Luckily, my need was for a very specific neighborhood, so I just used Maps' border to map out the dozen or so coords I needed and used the Polygon tool to draw over it myself. Works great, but I'm sorry they don't offer an API to fetch such a polygon - it obviously works in their system.